# Reality of the Wavefunction - Complex numbers and Degrees of Freedom in Configuration space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, complex-numbers

On the "reality" of the wavefunction, there seem to be two schools of thought on why treating $\psi$ as something more than a mathematical tool is erroneous:

1. $\psi$ involves complex numbers. Only Real numbers correspond to measurable quantities.
2. $\psi$ in configuration space has more degrees of freedom than physical space, therefore cannot correspond to physical reality.

My question is as follows:

- There's nothing magical or special about $i$. Complex numbers are just as "real" as Real numbers.  Both are components of our logical system of computation and together define the number plane - **why are physical measurements limited to corresponding to only 50% of the number plane?**

This is a follow-on to the question raised in ["Reality" of EM waves vs. wavefunction of individual photons - why not treat the wave function as equally "Real"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/163378/)

Comment: *"Complex numbers are just as "real" as Real numbers"* is false. A complex number is, by definition, a *pair* $(a,b)$ of two real numbers; a measurement must be only one number, hence one must extract one real number from the pair $(a,b)$ and we usually take the modulus square.

Comment: @Gennaro My point is that the math is incomplete without complex numbers; they may be combinations of 2 magnitudes, but the magnitude in the i vector is not "special" compared to the magnitude in the Real vector.  They are required for internal consistency just as real numbers are, but you raise another question: Why squaring as opposed to any other transformation? What is it about rotation by a magnitude identical to itself (if we're talking multiplying complex #s here) that's special?

Comment: Is the question "why is a complex vector space necessary for QM?" or "how do we form observables from complex number?". The answer to the latter is any positive function of the complex number: the modulus square is one and you can adjust the coefficients in front of the equations to make it fit with the experimental results.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco the second, which I'd rephrase as "why does psi squared correspond to observables (as opposed to any other positive function of the complex phase of psi)?"   My initial question still stands re: the treatment of the wavefunction as unreal simply because it relies on more than 3 degrees of freedom.

Comment: A quantum state represents the degree of information that we have on a given system. In mathematical terms, it is in fact a (noncommutative) probability; in other words it prescribes which values have to be expected for all the observables that characterize the system. It is convenient *but not necessary* to describe these probabilities with the aid of wavefunctions.  Aside from that, the "reality/fundamental level" of probability theories is more a matter of philosophy/interpretation than of physics/mathematics.

Comment: Those who do not accept an intrinsically probabilistic description of nature would say that a quantum state is "unreal", or rather not fundamental because it gives only a statistical description of a system. Those who accept quantum mechanics as a good theory to describe reality may consider quantum states as "real", or fundamental in giving the information available on a given system (with pure states giving the maximal possible information).

Comment: @yuggib Born's interpretation is only useful for single runs of an experiment.  It's equally (and I'd argue more usefully) valid to say that the wavefunction is a complete description of the field's behavior, full stop. The field is accurately and completely described by the wavefunction - the probabilistic nature of "particle" detection is a consequence of us putting in small quanta of energy at a time.  Put in enough energy in and you reproduce the entire psi^2 function.  Hence my question about treating the psi as unreal due to the requirements of config space, while strings get a pass.

Comment: To know a probability in a noncommutative probability theory by measurements you need to make a very very large (infinite) number of measurements for all the observables (that are an infinite number) of the system. Or at least you should need to make (an infinite number of) measurements for the observables "generating" the whole collection of observables. This is indeed a very demanding experimental task, and therefore the investigation of the quantum state is usually left to indirect measurements (e.g. like the ones Haroche did).

Comment: Hi James Pattarini, I removed you unrelated last subquestion about string theory, cf.  [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6833/2451) meta post.

Comment: Duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82613/

Comment: A wavefunction is not really a quantum state. It is more akin to the components of a vector given a basis. Anyhow, the major point is that the observables are not the wavefunction. You can even do QM using no complex numbers using the Wigner function instead, defined on the phase space.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The wavefunction is *not* "not real" because it's complex, it's "not real" because you can't measure it. Your "first school of thought" does not, to my knowledge, actually exist, and I don't understand what the second school of thought  is supposed to be - what is "$\psi$ in configuration space"? Why do you say that the real line is 50% of the number plane? (It's much less) Is the question, in the end, just why measured values are always real numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> why are physical measurements limited to corresponding to only 50% of the number plane?

This makes no sense: the real line is a set of measure zero in the complex plane. It does not represent the 50% of it.

If you want to go that way, I would say that $\mathbb R^n$ is "as real" as $\mathbb R$ anyway, so why restrict to $\mathbb C=\mathbb R^2$? why not to use $\mathbb R^3, \mathbb R^4,\cdots$?

The reason to use a complex wave-function is that it allows us to efficiently model the fact that Nature seems to add amplitudes, not probabilities. The *physics* of this are very well exemplified by the double slit experiment: try to think about that experiment without math. Now try to make up a mathematical model that reproduce the observed characteristics of the experiment. You should convince yourself that complex numbers do the work better than anything else, and this is the reason we want to introduce them.

After all, QM is just a mathematical model that is intended to reproduce observed phenomena. We use the model that works best, and standard QM is the best model we could find. It uses complex number as a mathematical tool, but physics is about modeling Nature, and not about finding the deep internal gears that make Nature work: reality is not mathematical. Nature doesn't work with complex numbers; we humans use them to model Nature.

Comment: I would strongly disagree with your last statements, but they are a matter of opinion. This comment is to let it be known that these are not facts.

Comment: I think physics _is_ about "finding the deep internal gears that make nature work".

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The imaginary part of a complex number is no less real than the real part. Both are necessary to give consistent mathematics and because mathematics play such a such an important part in out understanding of nature it is not surprizing that complex numbers appear in our theories of nature.

However, it is an observational fact that all our observations always just give us real values. Can you think any measurement that one can make that gives you a complex number as an answer? When I measure light using a detector I find that the detector always respond in proportion to the *intensity* of the light. When I do a quantum experiment I *count* particles. Both the intensity and the particle count are real numbers.

If I want to use quantum mechanics to predict how many particles I can expect to observe, then I have to compute the propability and that comes out to be the *modulus squared* $|\psi|^2=\psi\psi^*$ of the complex valued probability amplitude $\psi$. The same applies for the intensity. In this way both the real part and the imaginary part contribute equally. So they are equally important in the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

First you may misunderstand what the $\color{red}{\text{quantum state}}$  is.In fact it is a vector in Hilbert space rather than a point in configuration space (About this you can refer the book written by [Leonard Susskind](http://theoreticalminimum.com/)(the theoretic minimum:quantum mechanics).So there is not any relation between wave-function and configuration space.And finally you will find the so-called wave-function is nothing but the coefficients before the corresponding base vector.

If you are interested in quantum mechanics,I advise you can follow Leonard Susskind's course.Then you will ask the right question.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> On the "reality" of the wavefunction, there seem to be two schools of thought on why treating $\psi$ as something more than a mathematical tool is erroneous: 
>   1. $\psi$ involves complex numbers. Only Real numbers correspond to measurable quantities.

Who thinks that? Complex numbers are usually associated with a very real rotation. As for the reality of the wavefunction, take a look at weak measurement work by [Aephraim Steinberg et al](https://www.physics.utoronto.ca/~aephraim/) and by [Jeff Lundeen et al](http://www.photonicquantum.info/Research.html):

***"Direct Measurement of the Wavefunction***

*<sub>Chosen as 2nd most important Physics Breakthrough of 2011 by Physics World!</sub>*

*Central to quantum theory, the wavefunction is a complex distribution associated with a quantum system. Despite its fundamental role, it is typically introduced as an abstract element of the theory with no explicit definition. Rather, physicists come to a working understanding of it through its use to calculate measurement outcome probabilities through the Born Rule. Tomographic methods can reconstruct the wavefunction from measured probabilities. In contrast, we demonstrated a method to directly measure the wavefunction so that its real and imaginary components appear straight on our measurement apparatus. At the heart of the method is a joint measurement of position and momentum that is made possible by weak measurement (see below for what that is). As an example of the method we experimentally directly measured the transverse spatial wavefunction of a single photon. This new measurement  gives the wavefunction a plain and general meaning in terms of a specific set of operations in the lab."*

> 2. $\psi$ in configuration space has more degrees of freedom than physical space, therefore cannot correspond to physical reality.

I will never accept the pat line that *quantum physics surpasseth all human understanding*. We do physics to understand the world, not to shut up and calculate.

> There's nothing magical or special about $i$. Complex numbers are just as "real" as Real numbers.

Actually, real numbers *aren't* real. You can't point to a seventeen. In similar vein complex numbers aren't real either. But the things you count and measure are real. Like apples, and photon wavefunction. Why people ever suggested wavefunction is some kind of probability wave I shall never know. It's surely obvious that $|\psi|^2=\psi\psi^*$ because wavefunction interacts with wavefunction. It takes two to tango.

> Both are components of our logical system of computation and together define the number plane - why are physical measurements limited to corresponding to only 50% of the number plane?

I don't think they are. You can measure scalars and vectors. And tensors. Have a look at [complex numbers and electromagnetism](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=complex+numbers+rotation+electromagnetism). If you could give some particular references as to who's saying wavefunction can't be real because complex numbers are involved I'd be interested to read about it.

Comment: You are largely right. Also, I think that it is  helpful to refer the community here to the existence of "weak measurements"  enabling the measurement of the wave function of a single qm system, which points to its ontological nature.

Comment: @freecharly : thanks. What surprises me is that Steinberg et al and Lundeen et al did their [In Praise of Weakness](https://www.physics.utoronto.ca/~aephraim/PWMar13steinberg-final.pdf) work in [2011](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2011/dec/16/physics-world-reveals-its-top-10-breakthroughs-for-2011), and here we are five years later with people still saying wavefunction is some abstract probability thing.

Comment: I completely agree! There are too many physicists (also here)  following the infamous "shut up and calculate" way of thinking, you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the informative Physics World article! Here a link to an maybe  interesting book (building upon weak measurements):  "The Meaning of the Wave Function", by Shan Gao, which will be published 2017 by Cambridge University Press, and can, at present, be downloaded for free here:  http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/12608/

Comment: @freecharly : thanks, I've saved it, and will read it with interest.

Comment: Thx for the links to both of you

Comment: @John the question of whether weak measurements actually reveal anything at all about the wavefunction is far from settled.  See http://www.johnboccio.com/research/quantum/notes/14032362.pdf

Comment: @James Pattarini : noted, but I side with the _wavefunction is real_ guys on this.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the wavefunctions in QM are represented by complex numbers originates from the basic postulate of QM. That is that the wavefunction alone at t=0 should determine it at other times. This is unlike classical mechanics where both position and velocities at initial time are required in order to predict the evolution of the system. So one can write a wave going in +x direction by exp(ikx). Just multiply by exp(-iwt) and you can get a travelling wave in +x. Similarly if you write exp(-ikx) you know for sure it is a wave that would travel in -ve x direction.