# Continuity of measurement of observables in Classical Mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematics, phase-space, observables

In these lecture notes on QM by Simon Rhea & Richie Dadhley based on the first lecture [Frederic Schuller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbqA9Xn_iM0&list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxQVx5jRjbfRGEzWY_upS5K6&index=1&ab_channel=FredericSchuller), the following is mentioned on page-2:

> Recall that in classical mechanics an observable is a map $F : Γ → R$, where $Γ$ is the phase space of the system, typically given by the cotangent space $T^{*}Q$ of some configuration manifold $Q$. The map is taken to be at least continuous with respect to the standard topology on $R$ and an appropriate topology on $Γ$, and hence if $Γ$ is connected, we have $F (Γ) = I ⊆ R$.

What is the basis of wanting the Observable to be continous w.r.t standard topology on $R$ and approproriate topology on $\Gamma$?

Comment: Hi Tryst with Freedom. Welcome to Phys.SE. Linking to private clouds, dropbox, etc, is for various reasons not acceptable on SE, cf. [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11400/2451) meta post.

Comment: How do you suggest, I post the information here then @Qmechanic

Comment: Provide title etc of reference. Link to the official abstract/download page for the lecture notes if possible.

Comment: I think the request is simply too restrictive. The characteristic function of a set, say a ball,  of the phase space is an observable and it is not continuous. Yes-No observables are not continuous, they are just measurable.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Fair point. But after consulting some books on classical mechanics again, it seems that this (continuity, among other things) indeed is often postulated/ required.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1324/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Tobias, yes I also found that requirement and it is good if one wants to sticks to classical mechanics. If one wants to pass to QM the relevant structure is the $\sigma$ algebra one of elementary observables and there continuity should be relaxed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have small perturbations caused by e.g. the environment of the system, you want that these perturbations in the state only give a correspondingly small perturbation of the values of the observable in question.

If this were not the case, then basically a measurement (of a discontinuous observable) could just be a "random" output of the corresponding measurement device and as such the term "measurement" would be useless, i.e. one could not speak of an observable having a certain value (in some error bound) for a given system...